# How to delete tabs and newlines in json file

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a big json file which contain near 1000 line of information like this

```
 [
{
"title":
 ["\tНоутбук-трансформер HP Pavilion x360 13-u116ur (Z3A94EA)\r\t"],
 "price": 
["\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t42990", " "]}
]
```

I need to clear this file from tabs and new lines, give me advice how i can do it. When you will be give advices consider that i am a beginer). I tried to use regex package but i can't

Comment: use `strip()` i.e. `str = "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t42990"` then `str.strip()` will give you `"42990"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace()` function to do so:

```
for (key, values) in json_items.items():
    for i, value in enumerate(values):
        json_items[key][i] = value.replace("\t", "").replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "")
```

I used `json_items` for the name of `json` object You have.